# init method in non-static block Android

Tags: java, android, constructor, scrollview

I am extending ScrollView and in that i have used non-static block after constructors to initialize some of the variables.

Code

```
 public ScrollViewExtended(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollViewExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollViewExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ScrollViewExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        activity = (Activity) context;
        userActivityLogDao = new UserActivityLogDao();
        activity_name = activity.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    {
       init(getContext());
    }
```

I don't want to call init(context) method in each constructor. Thats why i have used non-static block. Can you please suggest if this is the correct way of doing it?

*I am able to run this code without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use the static context. If your problem is the fact that you don't want to call init in each constructor just use `this` instead of `super` (*explicit constructor invocation*). Eg

```
public ScrollViewExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ScrollViewExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(this);
}
```